# How do I draw the close, minimize, and maximize buttons in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I created a `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);` and so there is no title bar. Therefore, I am implementing my own. I wanted to know, however, before I continue whether there is a standard way to add the close, minimize, and maximize buttons in a native-os looking way (i.e. on windows it should look like the windows close buttons and the same for osx and linux).

Comment: You've eliminated the option to get native looking buttons by using a frameless window.  There's no function to draw them in Qt, you'll have to draw them yourself.  It is usually the point to *not* make them look like the native buttons when you do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I wanted to create a tabbed system like Chrome has. But, like chrome, I want the buttons to look native to the os.

Comment: Ah, yes, the nice things you can do when you have 150 programmers working on a product.

Comment: At least on Mac OS X, Google Chrome is actually *moving* the standard window controls, not omitting them. (It's doing so in a totally non-portable, OS-specific way.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QStyle` take a lot of standard icons base on OS style. You can get this icon from current OS style and then draw it by your self.

This is a simple implementation for reference.

```
class TitleBar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TitleBar(QWidget *parent = 0)
        :QWidget(parent)
    {
        QStyle *style = qApp->style();
        QIcon closeIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_TitleBarCloseButton);
        QIcon maxIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_TitleBarMaxButton);
        QIcon minIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_TitleBarMinButton);

        QPushButton *min = new QPushButton(this);
        QPushButton *max = new QPushButton(this);
        QPushButton *close = new QPushButton(this);
        min->setIcon(minIcon);
        max->setIcon(maxIcon);
        close->setIcon(closeIcon);

        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
        layout->setSpacing(0);
        layout->addWidget(min);
        layout->addWidget(max);
        layout->addWidget(close);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
};
```

Comment: Oddly enough, this doesnt do what I expected it to do: on OSX, the buttons look exactly the same as on windows...

Comment: `QMacStyle` is not implemented in Qt opensource edition 4.6.2. I don't know what about other edition. You can implement `QMacStyle` by your self.

Comment: Hm, just what I need. Will have to test this