# Native window controls Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons are not drawn in a matching way in Qt

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am using PySide - PyQt to develop an application. I would like to create my custom application frame and have the native close minimize and maximize buttons drawn on it. An example to this would be Apple's own iCal app of which the top application frame has these buttons on a custom image.

I tried:

```
ico = app.style().standardIcon(QStyle().SP_TitleBarMaxButton)
clo = QPushButton(panel_right_fill)
clo.setIcon(ico)
clo.move(20,40)
```

However neither the icon, nor the button matches the current OS' button style.

app here is a global `app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

How can I draw these buttons?

PS. self.style() does the same thing.

Comment: I have no experience in PyQt. I holp [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999148/how-do-i-draw-the-close-minimize-and-maximize-buttons-in-qt/14000604#14000604) can help you.

Comment: liuyi, thank you so much for your help. However I tried it and it did not work. I wonder if this is Mac specific or perhaps PySide or PyQt are not abstracting them correctly. Anyway, I decided not to create a custom frame as it causes lots of issues. Thank you though, very much!